# Scan images from sdcard and show in view flipper

Tags: android

I am developing a simple application which includes fetching images from sd card and displaying it in a gridview. please give me a solution for fetching images from sd card.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the link it might hep you http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

Implement FileNameFilter for filtering the file names .
here is an example http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=384

I think this should do the trick

Comment: thanks..but this is not am looking for actually..